# Y a-t-il des emprunts grammaticaux dans les variantes en contact avec d'autres langues?

Tags: grammaire, régionalismes

Il est assez clair que les variantes régionales du Français empruntent couramment du lexique aux autres langues avec lesquelles elles sont en contact. Voir par exemple [*Les emprunts dans le Dictionnaire des régionalismes de France*](http://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00004969/).

Est-ce vrai pour la grammaire ?

Par exemple : trouve-t-on en Français d'Alsace des particularités grammaticales issues de l'Alsacien ? Dans la région de Nice des emprunts au Provençal ou à l'Italien ? En Suisse au Suisse Allemand...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oui, cela existe, même si c'est plus rare que les emprunts lexicaux. On en trouve d'autant plus qu'on s'éloigne de régions où le français domine.

On rencontre dans certains coins de la Belgique des structures calquées sur le flamand. Par exemple, [à Bruxelles](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_de_Belgique#Faits_de_langue_propres_au_fran.C3.A7ais_de_Bruxelles) : « Voici Pierre, son ami. » (« *Daar komt Piet zijn vriend* »).

Le [français acadien](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_acadien) est assez teinté d'anglais. Par exemple on y trouve des verbes à particule : « Y'où se que t'arrive de ? » (« *Where are you coming from?* »).

Ces phénomènes sont plus fréquents dans certains dialectes africain, mais je ne les connais pas du tout. L'article de Jérémie Kouadio N’Guessan sur « la Situation linguistique » dans *Diagonales* n°26 (1993) consacré à la Côte d'Ivoire devrait t'intéresser ; il y déclare que « Le français populaire [ivoirien](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_de_C%C3%B4te_d%27Ivoire) est une espèce de sabir franco-ivoirien qui utilise des mots français (phonétiquement déformés) sur des structures syntaxiques des langues ivoiriennes ».

Comment: « Y'où se que t'arrive de ? » : le *Y* est volontaire ? *se* := *est-ce* ? l'absence de *s* à *arrive* est volontaire ? (À part ça, ça ressemble phonétiquement à du français…)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai fait confiance à [121.44.154.248](http://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fran%C3%A7ais_acadien&diff=47872232&oldid=47871894). Citation nécessaire, effectivement, même si j'ai aucune raison d'incroire. Le [livre de Raphaële Wiesmath](http://books.google.com/books?id=xwYbbUgbHeIC), peut-être ?

Comment: Je pense que le cas de Bruxelles est plus nuancé : si un néérlandophone utilisera effectivement la grammaire flamande avec un vocabulaire français, ça ne percole pas pour autant dans le language. Je n'ai jamais entendu un seul francophone dire _Pierre son ami_ au lieu de _l'ami de Pierre_. Pour moi, le phénomène est plus à attribuer à des personnes faisant des fautes en apprenant la langue.

Answer (score 5):

Oui. J'ai connaissance de quelques cas ; au Canada en particulier, il y a des tournures de phrase directement inspirées de l'anglais.

- Je suis tombé en amour - I fell in love
- Ca fait du sens - It makes sense.

Et beaucoup d'autres.

Comment: *Faire sens* fait aussi partie depuis peu du sociolecte de la politique.